# Como fazer um "depara" utilizando SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-update, dql

Possuo a seguinte estrutura na minha base de dados:

- Tabela `tgffin` com as colunas: `CODNAT`, `AD_CODNAT_OLD`
- Tabela `tgfnat` com as colunas: `CODNAT`, `AD_NAT_OLD`

Eu quero recuperar o valor de `tgfnat.CODNAT` quando  `tgfnat.AD_NAT_OLD = tgffin.AD_CODNAT_OLD` e posteriormente atualizar `tgffin.CODNAT` usando o valor value recuperado a partir da query anterior.

Como posso fazer isto utilizando uma única instrução SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Resolve com um update simples:

```
UPDATE tgffin, tgfnat
 SET tgffin.CODNAT = tgfnat.CODNAT
 WHERE tgfnat.AD_NAT_OLD = tgffin.AD_CODNAT_OLD;
```